Animating Buttons in unity using button elements
I am currently working on buttons in unity, I want to move through the buttons vertically, which I have already implemented with my created animations, and I want to add to move through them using my mouse, so I have tried using animation in button element, but the already created animation does not work, It only works with arrows like I wanted.
So I am seeking help now, I want to add to the button mouse click, I thought of using auto generate buttons, but then I dont think my vertical movement will no longer work. I can send the scripts, etc.

if you are using the new UI element set, then there are a number of things you can do.. which then work irrelevant of made on the fly or not.. theres a lot of tutorials on this on youtube
